# missing operator in query expression '.ID'

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working on a visual studio 2010 project wherein i make a database, then i create tables but everytime i run the program and click the button "create tables" message error occurs: "Invalid table name" and " syntax error (missing operator) in query expression .'ID' " can anyone please help me? this is my codes:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class table
Public Property Auditionees As String
Public Property TrainingAgencyDepartment As String
Public Property TrainingAgency As String

Public Property sID1 As String
Public Property sName1 As String
Public Property sField1 As String
Public Property sAge1 As String
Public Property sAddress1 As String
Public Property sContact1 As String

Public Property bkID2 As String
Public Property bkName2 As String
Public Property bkAddress2 As String
Public Property bkContact2 As String

Public Property bID3 As String
Public Property bAuditioned3 As String
Public Property bConfirmed3 As String
Public Property bSID3 As String
Public Property bBNUM3 As String



Private Sub queryCommand(ByVal query As String)
    Try
        Access.con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, Access.con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Invalid table name")
    End Try

    Access.con.Close()
End Sub

Private Access As New connection

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim query As String = ""


    query = "Create table " & Auditionees & " (AuditioneeeId counter primary key , AuditioneeName text, Talent text, Age int, Address text, Contact text ) "
    queryCommand(query)
    query = "Create table " & TrainingAgency & " (AgencyNumber counter primary key  , AgencyName text, Address text, Contact text ) "
    queryCommand(query)
    query = "Create table " & TrainingAgencyDepartment & " (DepartmentID counter primary key  , DateAuditioned date, DateConfirmed date, AuditioneeID int references  ) " & Auditionees & _
            " (AuditioneeId), AgencyNumber int unique references " & TrainingAgency & "(AgencyNumber)) "
    queryCommand(query)

    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What value of query throws the error?

Comment: im not sure but i think problem is in the "department id".

Comment: i tried setting it as "ID" instead of DepartmentId and then error message would be "missing operator in TrainingAgencyDepartment.ID"

Answer (score 1):

You should debug.
Try to find which run of queryCommand fails. It runs 3 times.

You should check, maybe one of the table names is missing.

You also might debug into queryCommand because you can get "Invalid table name" also when the connection is failed. Write out the exception as well.